# Delete all existing excel chart series

Tags: c#, excel, charts, excel-2010

I am modifying a line chart in excel and I want to remove all the series and add new series to the same chart.

I am using the foll code:

```
Excel.SeriesCollection serColl = chartpage.SeriesCollection();
Excel.Series ser = serColl.Item(4);
ser.Delete();
ser = serColl.Item(3);
ser.Delete();
ser = serColl.Item(2);
ser.Delete();
ser = serColl.Item(1);
ser.Delete();
```

But I wanted the code to be generic i.e. find the number of series and delete all in a loop.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the serColl has a count or length, you can use that to write a for loop to delete each one.

Answer (score 2):

Like so.

```
Excel.SeriesCollection serColl = chartpage.SeriesCollection();
while(seriesColl.Count > 0)
{
        seriesColl.Item(1).Delete();
}
```

Comment: This should be `seriesColl.Item(1).Delete();` as Excel uses 1-based indexing.